# I can't send handlePan: to my UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview

I tried to do something that I thought would be straightforward just now. But it creates an error, which has led to a couple of questions.

First of all, I'm trying to do a drag operation in a `UICollectionView`. But I still want that view to be scrollable. I've not found anything (yet?) that is a straightforward solution to doing this.

I observed that at `viewDidLoad` time, my `UICollectionView` already has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which target action that is set to the view and selector `handlePan:`.

So I thought... I'll fetch that gesture recognizer, and insert a shim, so that I get an opportunity first to deal with the pan gesture. If it satisfies my drag requirements, I'll handle that, otherwise, I'll let it take its regular course. To effect this, I added this code to my `viewDidLoad` in my `UICollectionViewController` subclass:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in self.collectionView.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([gesture isKindOfClass: [UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        [gesture removeTarget: nil action:nil]; // clear out the default handlePan: target
        [gesture addTarget: self action: @selector(drag:)]; // replace it with my own shim 
    }
}
```

Which works fine (I've done this with the pinch recognizer). But when I implement my shim method:

```
- (IBAction)drag:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"drag %@", sender);
    [self.collectionView handlePan: sender];
}
```

Xcode emits an error:

```
No visible @interface for 'UICollectionView' declares the selector 'handlePan:'
```

This confuses me. I get that that method does not show up in the documented interface of UIScrollView, but I could see that that was the selector it was targeted at. I might expect a warning, but not an error, I thought Objective-C method dispatch was runtime and dynamic. How would one overcome this?

Tangentially, I'm curious if there's a better/idiomatic/canonical way to implement dragging on a UIScrollView and still maintain scroll (but, even if I'm doing it all wrong, I still want to understand the error).

Comment: Did you dump the original target of the pan recognizer, my guess is it isn't the UICollectionView.

Comment: Slapped an `NSLog` on it before wiping the original target: `2014-03-18 11:50:07.832 myValve[1107:60b] defaul pan gesture: <UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x17d90660; state = Possible; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UICollectionView 0x1837f200>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<UICollectionView 0x1837f200>)>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misread the original question, since it's Xcode complaining at compile time about the unknown selector you can cast the target to id to get around the warning.  I'm still not sure I'd do it, or sure that Apple won't bounce it for using private API's, but here it is:

```
[(id)self.collectionView handlePan: sender];
```